# Progress bar on file uploading via FTP [C++]

Tags: c++, ftp, progress-bar

I've written a small program which is able to upload files to a server via ftp. Because of the large size of some files I want to create a progress bar for the user. So during the upload I need to know at certain intervals how many bytes have been sent to the server in order to derive the percentage of the file that has been uploaded. What I have tried so far:

While I call the function FtpPutFile() to upload the file, I spawn a thread with the following code:

```
hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);
hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, ftpserver, port, user, pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0,    0); 
int filesize = 0; // 2GB max

hFile = FtpOpenFile(hFtpSession,szFileTitle,GENERIC_READ,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,0);
filesize = FtpGetFileSize(hFile,0); 
cout << "Size: " << filesize << endl;
```

However this doesn't seem to work as *filesize* keeps returning a value of -1. I think this is due to the fact that I'm writing to a file (uploading part) and at the same time I'm trying to read it to get the file size. And I think this is not possible (please correct me if I'm wrong).

My main question: *is there another way to create a progress bar for ftp uploading?* Perhaps counting the bytes **before** they are uploaded using the function readBytesCount() (not sure if this is possible at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to:

1. Call [`InternetSetStatusCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385120.aspx) to set a function that will be called periodically during the transfer.
2. Pass a (non-zero) value the last parameter to `FtpOpenFile`. This will be passed back to your status callback function during the transfer.

Then, during the FTP operation, your callback function will be invoked periodically with information about the progress of the transfer, which it can then display to the user.

I don't believe this will let you show actual bytes as they're being transferred though -- if memory serves it mostly shows the discrete steps in a transfer, like opening the handle, resolving names, sending/receiving cookies, and finally closing the handle.

To deal with the actual bytes being written during the transfer of the file itself, you'd typically read a buffer-full of data from the local file, then write that buffer with `InternetWriteFile`. With that, you can compute the percentage transferred as the number of bytes written so far divided by the total size of the file (and multiply by 100).

Comment: Thanks for your response Jerry. Could you please elaborate on the last paragraph? After reading a data buffer from the file, how does one remember the position in the file (so I don't send the same data multiple times)?

Comment: @Rob: well, you're basically going to have a normal loop to read a chunk and then write it out, 'til you reach the end of the file. Unless you're doing overlapped reads, you don't need to explicitly remember the file position -- you can just retrieve it with (for example) `std::istream::tellg`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved such a problem by sending the file by chunks and updating the progress in place of sending the whole file by one call to `FtpPutFile`

I mean:

```
 FtpOpenFile(...)
 for( ... )
 {
    InternetWriteFile(... dwChunkSize...)
    UpdateProgressBar(dwChunkSize)        
 }
 InternetCloseHandle(...)
```